# Hiding columns in table JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This script stops working the moment I add a table inside a table, so how to get it worked?
I don't need any jQuery solutions, I want pure JavaScript. Here's my **script** found on the Internet:

```
<script>

  function show_hide_column(col_no, do_show) {

    var stl;
    if (do_show) stl = 'block'
    else         stl = 'none';

    var tbl  = document.getElementById('id_of_table');
    var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var row=1; row<rows.length;row++) {
      var cels = rows[row].getElementsByTagName('td')
      cels[col_no].style.display=stl;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Here's my **HTML**:

```
<table id='id_of_table' border=1>
  <tr><td colspan="4"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></td></tr>
  <tr><td>  2</td><td>   two</td><td>   deux</td><td>     zwei</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  3</td><td> three</td><td>  trois</td><td>     drei</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  4</td><td>  four</td><td>quattre</td><td>     vier</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  5</td><td>  five</td><td>   cinq</td><td>f&uuml;nf</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  6</td><td>   six</td><td>    six</td><td>    sechs</td></tr>
</table>
```

And here's my **Form**:

```
<form>
  Enter column no: <input type='text' name=col_no><br>
  <input type='button' onClick='javascript:show_hide_column(col_no.value,  true);' value='show'>
  <input type='button' onClick='javascript:show_hide_column(col_no.value, false);' value='hide'>
</form>
```

Comment: Han and Jabba now collaberate on a script language :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabba_the_Hutt

Comment: just as a sidenote: if you need to have nested tables, it seems like you have bigger problems than a not-working javascript snippet. don't use tables for layout: http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Comment: Ya, nested tables is causing problems, I know i can work around with a JavaScript but tweaking in Script can be possible...

Comment: JabbaScript for the win! http://www.schnell.net/jabbascript.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can leverage the `col` tag and then the solution is straightforward using only vanilla JavaScript. The `col` tag has only a few CSS attributes, but visibility is one of them:

```js
function show_hide_column( col_no, do_show ){
   const table  = document.getElementById( 'id_of_table' )
   const column = table.getElementsByTagName( 'col' )[col_no]
   if ( column ){
      column.style.visibility = do_show?"":"collapse";
   }
}

const btnHide = document.getElementById( 'btnHide' )
btnHide.addEventListener( "click", () => show_hide_column( 2, false ))

const btnShow = document.getElementById( 'btnShow' )
btnShow.addEventListener( "click", () => show_hide_column( 2, true ))
```

```html
 <table id='id_of_table' border=1>
      <col class="col1"/>
      <col class="col2"/>
      <col class="col3"/>
      <col class="col4"/>
      <tr><td colspan="4"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></td></tr>
      <tr><td>  2</td><td>   two</td><td>   deux</td><td>     zwei</td></tr>
      <tr><td>  3</td><td> three</td><td>  trois</td><td>     drei</td></tr>
      <tr><td>  4</td><td>  four</td><td>quattre</td><td>     vier</td></tr>
      <tr><td>  5</td><td>  five</td><td>   cinq</td><td>fÜnf</td></tr>
      <tr><td>  6</td><td>   six</td><td>    six</td><td>    sechs</td></tr>
    </table>
    <button id="btnHide">hide French</button>
    <button id="btnShow">show French</button>
```

References:

- [col](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col)
- [visibility on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html#visibility)

Comment: +1, nice! I didn't even know the `col` tag... Learn something every day. :-)

Comment: Nice one, thanks!!! For users who do a quick look: to hide a column, add a 'col' tag as described above and set "visibility: collapse" on it (you can just identify it with an ID and call it with getElementById) ;-)

Comment: Was hoping to use that as well, as I have a table with `<col>` elements, but for some reason in Chrome setting `visibility = collapse` does not work for me :(

Comment: Such a shame that this doesn't seem to work universally as this is the perfect solution - it's exactly what `<col>` is for. Firefox is ok but it doesn't work in WebKit-based browsers (I tested chrome and safari)

Comment: If you'd like this to work in Google Chrome, please vote for the bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174167

Comment: When you hide a column, the space gained isn't given to the remaining columns.

Comment: This works in Chrome here in 2022

Answer (score 10):

You could use `children` and check their `tagName` to make sure they're `td`'s. Something like this:

```
function show_hide_column(col_no, do_show) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('id_of_table');
    var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var row = 0; row < rows.length; row++) {
        var cols = rows[row].children;
        if (col_no >= 0 && col_no < cols.length) {
            var cell = cols[col_no];
            if (cell.tagName == 'TD') cell.style.display = do_show ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3DjhL/2/.

**Edit**:
In fact, I've just remembered the `rows` and `cols` properties, which make it even simpler. See http://jsfiddle.net/3DjhL/4/ to see it in action.

```
function show_hide_column(col_no, do_show) {
    var rows = document.getElementById('id_of_table').rows;

    for (var row = 0; row < rows.length; row++) {
        var cols = rows[row].cells;
        if (col_no >= 0 && col_no < cols.length) {
            cols[col_no].style.display = do_show ? '' : 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and if you think the column numbers should start at 1 (which they don't), you'll have to offset that somewhere. For example at the top of `show_hide_column()`:

```
col_no = col_no - 1;
```

Comment: nah, doesn't hide any columns for me

Comment: Your problem is that `getElementsByTagName` returns all the so-named descendants of the element in question, not just the immediate child nodes with that name. Your script is likely throwing an "array out of bounds" error on `cels[col_no].style.display=stl;`.

Following @PPvG's lead is your best bet.

Comment: @V413HAV my apologies, I'd made a (small) mistake. I did say "something like this", not "exactly this", but I digress. It works now, as you can see in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing here is the selector, it could be vanilla or jquery:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#yourtable tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').forEach(el=>el.style.display = 'none')
```

From the code above, the **nth-child(1)** selector has a 1-based index, there you define the column you want to hide ;)

Comment: The only issue with here is that the code above will not hide the column header. To do that you will need to add document.querySelectorAll("#yourtable tbody tr td:nth-child(1)").forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none') with the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation where it would have been a very big hassle to modify every single TD value and add the appropriate class name so I could toggle it. As a result I wrote some JavaScript to do that automatically. Please see the following code.

```
  tbl = document.getElementById("Mytable")
  classes = getClasses(tbl.rows[0]);
  setClasses(tbl, classes);
  toggleCol("col0");
  toggleCol("col1");



function getClasses(row){
    var cn = 0;
    var classes = new Array();
    for(x=0; x < row.cells.length; x++){
        var cell = row.cells[x];
        var c = new Column(cell.textContent.trim(), cell.offsetLeft, cell.offsetLeft + cell.offsetWidth, x);
        classes[x]= c;
    }
    return classes;
}

function Column(name, left, right, cols) {
    this.name = name;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.cols = cols;
}

function setClasses(table, classes){
    var rowSpans = new Array();
    for(x=0; x < table.rows.length; x++){
        var row = table.rows[x]; 
        for(y=0; y < row.cells.length; y++){
            var cell = row.cells[y];
            for(z=0; z < classes.length; z++){
              if(cell.offsetLeft >= classes[z].left && cell.offsetLeft <= classes[z].right){
                cell.className = "col" + classes[z].cols;
              }
            }
        }    
    }
}

function toggleCol(name){ 
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName(name); 
  for(x=0; x < cols.length; x++){ 
    cols[x].style.display= (cols[x].style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'; 
   }
}
```

In my example I take a look at the first row to set the top level header (In my example I had several who had colspans). It uses the offsetLeft and offsetWidth to determine the range of the top header (which in my cases has sub headers), so that all sub-columns would toggle with its parent.

Based on these values setClasses sets the appropriate classes to all the elements.

In my example I then toggle "col0" and "col1", so they would be invisible (Running the function again would make them visible again).