# Activeadmin - user option for hide and unhide column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is there any solution in [activeadmin](https://activeadmin.info/index.html) for option where user can hide/unhide column?

Comment: Hide it from what/where?

Comment: a column in the indexes? according to the docs you presented, doesn't seem so. Probably you could reload the page with the column you want to hide/unhide - although it is unoptimal in this day and age -, or using AJAX calls to do it without reloading. Or just to create CSS buttons that implement "visibility:hidden" or something.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, no. You would need to define a data structure to hold the user's preferences then define your index something like:

```
index do
  column :title unless current_user.hide_column?(:title)
  ...
end
```

The simplest way to hold the preferences would be a UserColumnPreference resource which itself could be managed through ActiveAdmin. More sophisticated solutions might involve using AJAX, subclassing ActiveAdmin::IndexAsTable, etc.

If you don't need to persist the preference then a simple JavaScript to manipulate the HTML table on the page will do, eg. [Hiding columns in table JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754013/hiding-columns-in-table-javascript) This is unrelated to ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I found a neat solution for this.  Saving it as a session variable.

Complete solution:

This creates a button on the index page that says show or hide images depending on the state:

```
  action_item :toggle_image_view, only: :index do
    link_to (session['hide_images'] || false) ? t('views.admin.show_images') : t('views.admin.hide_images') , toggle_image_view_admin_person_poses_path
  end
```

This toggles the session key and shows the index page again:

```
  collection_action :toggle_image_view, method: :get do
    session['hide_images'] = !(session['hide_images'] || false)
    redirect_to collection_path
  end
```

Here you see the column that will get displayed or not depending on the session variable.  Default is set to display them.

```
  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :camera
    unless (session['hide_images'] || false)
      column :image
    end
    actions
  end
```