# How do I show/hide an entire column when a button is clicked?

Tags: python, html, show-hide

I have a webapp and the results page that returns a table with multiple columns, I want my button to either hide or show the column.

I tried creating a function that does this and then call the function onclick

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Show/Hide</button>`

```
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }       

    </script>
```

this is the table it produces, and I want one of the columns to hide and show

```
        <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Table</th>
                    <th scope="col">Column</th>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Data Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Length</th>
                    <th scope="col" id="myDIV">Data Stewards</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for r in results %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{r.tbl_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{r.col_name}}</td>
                        {% if r.FreeText!="nan" %}
                            <td>{{r.FreeText}}</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td></td>
                        {% endif %}
                        <td>{{r.DataType_Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{r.DataType_MaxLength}}</td>

                        {% if r.tag_cat_name=="Data Stewards" %}
                            <td> {{r.tag_name}}</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td></td>
                        {% endif %}


                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

in this format it only hides/shows the Data Stewards column heading, not the entire column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding columns in table JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754013/hiding-columns-in-table-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could give the `td`, which you want to show/hide, the same class. Assuming, that you want to do that for the Data Stewards, it could look something like this:

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Table</th>
            <th scope="col">Column</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Data Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Length</th>
            <th scope="col" class="myDIVs">Data Stewards</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for r in results %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{r.tbl_name}}</td>
                <td>{{r.col_name}}</td>
                {% if r.FreeText!="nan" %}
                    <td>{{r.FreeText}}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td></td>
                {% endif %}
                <td>{{r.DataType_Name}}</td>
                <td>{{r.DataType_MaxLength}}</td>    
                {% if r.tag_cat_name=="Data Stewards" %}
                    <td class="myDIVs"> {{r.tag_name}}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td class="myDIVs"></td>
                {% endif %}    
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  const myDIVs = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIVs");
  for (let i = 0; i < myDivs.length; i++) {
    if (myDivs[i].style.display === "none") {
        myDivs[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
        myDivs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```